# Raspberry Pi autonomous headless setup

Tags: setup

everytime I setup a new sd card for a pi, I first have to ssh to the running pi and then start to install some software via shell commands.

Isn't there a way to drop a shell setup file to the fat32 partition of a fresh sd card which then gets executed on the first run?

Comment: Probably easier to put it into the root filesystem, unless a constraint is you can't access anything but the first partition.  Enabling/activating a systemd service is really just a matter of creating a symlink, so it can be done without the system running.  If that is too complicated, I think `/etc/rc.local` still runs by default, you could use or replace that.  Beware tasks that require more than a second or two should fork and exit the foreground.

Comment: my main system is a windows device. I guess that says it all 

Comment: "everytime I setup a new sd card" how often? why? I setup a SD Card about every 2 years when a new OS is released and then clone.

Comment: you know, I also install additional software and I don't like to do it manually every time. In addition, when I experiment with setups, I would like to have the chance to easily roll back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that was discussed in the past and has some suggestions to run a script only on the first boot up from the fat32 boot partition. On a virgin Raspbian image you will find a [script call to `init_resize.sh` for first boot up in `/boot/cmdline.txt`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96536/79866). You may modify it with some knowledge of scripting but there is a [script to execute on first boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105534/79866). You can find it also on github at [pi-boot-script](https://gitlab.com/JimDanner/pi-boot-script).

Comment: than - this is the answer I was searching for!